# Get the last 24 months of data from Netezza database

Tags: netezza

I want to pull the last 24 months of data but excluding the most 2 recent quarters (current quarter and last quarter) from our netteza database.  The format of date field in the database is like this: YYYY-Q-MM

```
2015411 = Year=2016  Quarter=4  month= 11
2013108 = Year=2013  Quarter=1  month= 8
```

The expected time frame should be data from October 2014 to September 2016. We are using calendar year Jan to Mar is Q1 and Apr to Jun is Q2 etc. This is the query i am using but it pulls everything for the last 27 months but i only want the last 24 months but excluding the most 2 recent Quarters.

```
select * from myTable where substring (month_key,1,4) || substring (month_key, 6,7) || ''01'' > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL ''27 months''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the built in quarter evaluation.

The query below highlights the desired values

```
select add_months(to_date(to_char(to_date(to_char(current_date,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ')-1,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ'),-24) as "24 months prior to 2 quarters ago"
,to_date(to_char(to_date(to_char(current_date,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ')-1,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ') "2 quarters ago"
```

This is it in your example:

```
select * from myTable 
where date_value between select add_months(to_date(to_char(to_date(to_char(current_date,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ')-1,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ'),-24)
and to_date(to_char(to_date(to_char(current_date,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ')-1,'YYYYQ'),'YYYYQ')
```